# How do I apply a cursor theme in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10, themes, cursor

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I found a cursor theme that I really like however, when I use the GNOME tweak tool to apply it it doesn’t change but when I open a program like Firefox its there but not on the desktop or the launcher bar.

I have tried logging out and back in 3 times and restarting twice. please help me I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://www.chaaps.com/how-to-install-new-cursor-themes-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 3):

Gnome Tweak Tool does not set cursors for X. Try running:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

You'll get a list of installed cursor themes, and it will ask you which you want to apply. After that, you can restart Unity/Compiz/X/Ubuntu.